# Is there a way to check if a workflow is completed using Javascript?

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, workflow-activity

I created a form that start a workflow automatically when an item is created, and I redirect to html page that shows a message like "Processing... please wait.", and I wait 3 seconds and so redirect to a page with results of the workflow.

Instead of wait 3 seconds, I want to create a javascript that check if the workflow is completed, then redirect to results page.

I am using SharePoint 2010 Foundation

Is there way?

Comment: Please add the version of SharePoint (2007,2010,2013) as a tag to your question.

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande ok. I added the tags. It is SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried this method, but I think it should work. If you use the Lists web service to query for the particular item, you should be able to retrieve the workflow status column and see it's value. It should give you In Progress/Complete. In your code, you'd just need to check that status and wait/recheck in a few seconds or redirect to your page based on the results.

Edit:
I tried using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) and it does work:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='WFColumn' /></ViewFields>",
    listName: "MyList",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("ows_WFCol" === 5)){
                console.log("It's complete");
          }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm! I love SPServices! How I lived all this time without it???? Thanks!

Comment: Can I get/extract the value of Comments field that's residing in the InfoPath form,[ SP default approval form] with the help of spservices? my requirement is to know, why the default SP 2010 approval workflow was approved, and why the workflow was rejected. ( to extract the  reasons for approval/ rejection etc,. )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dom/debug in the browser(press F12) then find the 'name =" "' atribute  of the column. Then use that name with Spservcies. For my example I trigger my wf by updating a column then returning a workflow status colmn value:

```
 function CopyStrategyDocuments(StrategyDocID, StrategyDocLocation){



                                $().SPServices({
                                        operation: 'UpdateListItems',
                                        listName: 'Case Attachments',
                                        ID: StrategyDocID,
                                        valuepairs: [['Copy_x002d_Document','Yes'],['Copy_x002d_To',StrategyDocLocation]],
                                                                        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {


                                              var test = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").attr("ows_CopyDocu");
                                               alert(test)
                                        //  

                                        }
                                });





      };
```

[image]